# Are there any good algebraic geometry books to recommend?

Tags: soft-question, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, big-list, algebraic-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(undergraduate) Algebraic Geometry Textbook Recomendations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/undergraduate-algebraic-geometry-textbook-recomendations)

I am interested in algebraic number theory and I am recently acquainted with the theory of valuations, which further leads to Riemann-Roch theory, and which is closely related to algebraic geometry, and the algebraic-K-theory.
Therefore, my problem is:

> Are there excellent introductory books of the theory of Algebraic Geometry to recommend?

Since I know in general nothing about this theory, I may want a book which explains the ideas as clear as possible and which at the mean time contains as much material as possible.
If I am asking too much, then any good book in your view suffices.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/undergraduate-algebraic-geometry-textbook-recomendations

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998/best-algebraic-geometry-text-book-other-than-hartshorne

Comment: It seems better to collect these recommendations at one place, therefore I'm voting to close.

Comment: Perhaps we shall make an area for this kind of questions...

Comment: And I cannot find my community button, hence I will appreciate everyone who makes this community wiki, thanks.

Comment: I uesd to be able to do this, there must be some errors.....

Comment: @awllower: You can't do it yourself for questions, you can only do it yourself for answers. Next time, you should flag your question for moderator attention click on "other" and ask them to turn the question into Community Wiki. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: @Theo Burhler: I see, and thank very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned at another post [Teaching myself differential topology and differential geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/teaching-myself-differential-topology-and-differential-geometry/22583#22583)

If you are interested in learning Algebraic Geometry I recommend the books of my Amazon list. They are in recommended order to learn from the beginning by yourself:

http://www.amazon.com/lm/RHQS8Y3V7LJRQ/ref=cm_pdp_lm_title_1

In particular, from that list, a quick path to understand basic Algebraic Geometry would be to read **Bertrametti et al**. *"Lectures on Curves, Surfaces and Projective Varieties"*, **Shafarevich**'s "*Basic Algebraic Geometry"* vol. 1, 2 and **Perrin**'s *"Algebraic Geometry an Introduction"*. But then you are entering the world of abstract algebra.

There is no a single complete book and much less explaining the ideas as clearly as possible. If you are starting from the very beginnig, I recommend these in this order: Karen **Smith's, Beltrametti, Hulek, Safarechiv vol. 1, Perrin, Shafarevich vol. 2** and then scheme theory with **Ueno**'s three volumes.... then you can jump with enough background to the bible by **Hartshorne**, or **Griffiths/Harris** for the more complex geometric side.

Comment: Alvarez: As I said, I have some foundation to read the algebraic number theory while lack that of the algebraic geometry.  And it seems that the books recommended here are all pretty suitable, and I cannot understand the *Bible of Hartshorn* indeed, anyway, thanks very much.

Comment: And I will wait for other answers; nevertheless, if it turns out to be the best answer, I will accept it, I just want to wait, sorry.

Comment: would you mind moving this answer to the other question?

Comment: I will elaborate more and move it, no problem.