# Shortest path to frontier

Tags: soft-question

I am just finishing my second semester in Abstract Algebra, we covered most of Dummit Foote, and I found part v the intro to Algebraic Geometry interesting so was looking up "roadmaps" to research readiness and  found this rather intimidating - [Path to Basics in Algebraic Geometry from HS Algebra and Calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285201/path-to-basics-in-algebraic-geometry-from-hs-algebra-and-calculus/285355#285355)  . I am not the fastest student and this would take me forever to get through. I just looked at Hartshorne and I feel like I'm some way of being able to start working through it. So I was wondering, mainly for perspective , if one were to construct such paths for some other major research areas which would maybe atleast look the least daunting? I hope this question is slightly less subjective than simply asking which is the toughest field though I would be interested on opinions on this as well.

Comment: Is your question "Which area of research-level Mathematics is the *easiest*?" or "Which requires the least background knowledge?"...? Also, is this with a view to pursuing research-level mathematics: if so, you'll find that most Grad schools require a breadth of knowledge (at entry) far wider than the single field you'll eventually specialise in.