# Book recommendation on Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a beginners' book on algebraic geometry, by beginner I mean something akin to Elementary Topology Problem Textbook by Ivanov, Netsvetaev, Kharlamov and Viro. Something for undergrads that covers the basics and still manages to explore in some depth the more complex themes of the field.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285201/path-to-basics-in-algebraic-geometry-from-hs-algebra-and-calculus/285355#285355 or any of the answerer's other posts addressing this question.

Comment: I think you're asking for a bit much of a single text, but take a look at [Karen Smith's book](http://www.amazon.com/An-Invitation-Algebraic-Geometry-Universitext/dp/0387989803).