# Geometry textbooks for university students

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a master's student with interests in algebraic geometry and number theory. And I have a good collection of textbooks on various topics in these two fields. Also, as part of my undergraduate curriculum, I learnt *abstract algebra* from the books by [Dummit-Foote](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471433349), [Hoffman-Kunze](http://a.co/1W64BrJ), [Atiyah-MacDonald](http://a.co/1uYmtzq) and [James-Liebeck](http://a.co/gyrtqPt); *analysis* from the books by [Bartle-Sherbert](http://a.co/7KGN3kI), [Simmons](http://a.co/hc4fRwH), [Conway](http://a.co/dKqgRWX), [Bollobás](http://a.co/cOhqtsK) and [Stein-Shakarchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princeton_Lectures_in_Analysis); *topology* from the books by [Munkres](http://a.co/iK0ya7p) and [Hatcher](http://a.co/dI1GZ8T); and *discrete mathematics* from the books by [Brualdi](http://a.co/btl8Hz3) and [Clark-Holton](http://a.co/gW8bhLL). I also had basic courses in *differential geometry* and *multivariable calculus* but no particular textbook was followed. (Please note that none of the above-mentioned textbooks was read from cover to cover).

As you can see, I didn't learn much *geometry* during my past 4 years of undergraduate mathematics. In high school, I learnt a good amount of Euclidean geometry but after coming to university geometry appears very mystical to me. I keep hearing terms like hyperbolic/spherical geometry, projective geometry, differential geometry, Riemannian manifold etc. and have read general maths books on them, like the books by [Hartshorne](http://a.co/hGNUGbO), [Ueno-Shiga-Morita-Sunada](http://a.co/70w6GAS) and [Thorpe](http://a.co/a2Cd2Xp).

I will be grateful if you could suggest a series of books on geometry (like [Stein-Shakarchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princeton_Lectures_in_Analysis)'s Princeton Lectures in Analysis) or a book discussing various flavours of geometry (like [Dummit-Foote](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471433349)). I am aware that [Coxeter](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/16005685.H_S_M_Coxeter) has written a series of textbooks in geometry, and I have read [Geometry Revisited](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/207954.Geometry_Revisited) in high school (which I enjoyed). If these are the ideal textbooks, then where to start? Also, what about the geometry books by [Hilbert](http://a.co/aZkBijF)?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Look up John Lee's texts: Introduction to Topological Manifolds and Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. These might be of interest to you.

Comment: @Clayton I looked at Lee's  Introduction to Topological Manifolds at the library. I jumped to the chapter on CW complexes and I liked it (it's much better than Hatcher). Thanks.

Comment: When I think “reference request related to algebraic geometry” I think “Javier Álvarez”. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/285355/120540) for instance (and many of his other [tag:reference-request] answers contain good things). I don’t think it’s mentioned in that answer, but Shaferavich has a book or two on geometry that may be worth looking at.

Comment: For differential geometry: Noel Hicks' "Notes on Differential Geometry" and Milnor's "Morse Theory".  Also, books on general relativity can be good ways to learn some geometry (e.g. Carroll's "Spacetime and Geometry").

Comment: @pjs36 Thanks for sharing Javier Álvarez's nice answer.

Comment: Do Carmo's twins are a good introduction to differential geometry. They are very visual and easy reads.

Answer (score 2):

Geometry is really a very broad term and it encompases many different realms of mathematics.

Usually, the main dichotomy is between algebraic geometry and differential geometry.

For algebraic geometry, 2 series come to mind:

1.Kenji Ueno, Algebraic Geometry (these are 3 monographs by AMS)
 2.Cox, O'Shea , Little: 1)Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms/2) Using Algebraic Geometry

Also there are the vast notes by Ravi Vakil on his website, which I highly recommend (I think that studying Ueno and then Vakil will give you a very good foundation in algebraic geometry).

Now for Differential Geometry again 2 series come to mind:

1. John Lee: Topological Manifolds/Smooth Manifolds/Curvature
2. Tu: An Introduction to Manifolds/ Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology (allong with Bott)/Connections, Curvature and Characteristic Classes.

Also, one could start reading Guillemin & Pollack: Differential Topology and then the classical Milnor: Topology from the differential viewpoint.

Finally, you could also take a look in Berger: A panoramic view of Riemannian Geometry where the author aims tou give a quick but to the point description of all the areas of that vast subject.

Comment: I will look at Ueno's books. Also, do you mean Guillemin and Pollack: Differential Topology? I couldn't find any Differential geometry book by them.

Comment: @rationalbeing Yes, you are right, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Nick A., are you sure there's a book by Tu called 'introduction to smooth manifolds' ? all i found was '[introduction to manifolds](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Manifolds-Universitext-Loring-W/dp/1441973990)'. however, there's a book by john lee called '[introduction to smooth manifolds](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Smooth-Manifolds-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1441999817/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=J8WDYX6TJZR9326M714F)'

Comment: @BCLC ooops you are right I will edit that . Thanks !

Comment: @NickA. Thanks too!