# A good book for dimension, depth and geometric meaning

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm studying Krull's dimension, depth, projective dimension of rings and modules and the relations among them. Could you recommend me a good book in which these concepts and the geometric meaning are explained?

Comment: are you studying this material with an eye towards algebraic geometry?

Comment: @user1090793
 exactly, I already know the definitions in the "pure algebraic context". I would like to understand them more deeply.

Comment: There are several excellent answers already on this site; in particular, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/reference-for-algebraic-geometry/46921#46921