# Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Algebraic Geometry text book? (other than Hartshorne)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998/best-algebraic-geometry-text-book-other-than-hartshorne)

I want to study algebraic geometry. Anyone can advise me a good introductory book? my knowledge of abtracta algebra (commutative and non comutative) are good.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998/best-algebraic-geometry-text-book-other-than-hartshorne

Comment: Whatever you do, don't even think of getting close to Hartshorne's book. Most probably it will fill you with dispair and confussion. This is a great book for someone with a rather hefty background already or for consultation.

Comment: Miles Reid's book *Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry* is a good place to start.