# What would be the most rigorous book to study algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves on my own?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, book-recommendation, arithmetic-geometry

I would like to study algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves on my own but are there suggestions where to start? Namely, I like very rigorous way to do mathematics and I was suggested Liu's book "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves". But I found it not so well written because for example in exercise 1.1.2 he didn't say what he means by $A$, there are many issues on errata, and I think there are hyphenation problems in the book. For example on page viii there is a wrong hyphenation concern-ing.

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998/best-algebraic-geometry-text-book-other-than-hartshorne

Comment: The paperback edition of Liu's book has a lot of these corrections. And many authors don't maintain errata as Liu does. Hyphenation is probably the least of your problems in life! As far as being expedient, self-contained, and geared toward arithmetic applications I'm not sure that you're going to find anything better.

Comment: Anyway, one book you might want to take a look at is Bosch's *Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra*.