# Another question about how to learn algebraic geometry...

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

I've been trying to learn some algebraic geometry (level of generality: working over an algebraically closed ground field but not afraid of using the language of sheaves and cohomology etc.)

The problem I'm having with it is that most of the references I'm using (Milne's notes on AG, Perrin's Algebraic Geometry, Mumford's Red Book etc.) just seem like endless streams of technical results and whilst I can appreciate most of the concrete examples ("oh look - that's a singularity"...), I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to be doing. On the other hand, books like Reid's Undergraduate AG makes me feel like I'm not sure what the definitions are (if that makes sense to someone!).

At the minute my approach is to check everything line by line (if I can!) and try to build up a picture of how the technicalities fit together into a bigger picture. I've also tried to do the exercises in Chapter 1 of Hartshorne but a lot of them seem too difficult for me at the moment (there feels a big gap between the technicalities of the chapters in the books and the concrete nature of the examples).

Does anyone have some magical book recommendation that I've missed or some other approach that helped them learn the subject?

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, there are many very good books, which combine both: strict definitions but not endless technical points. See for example the recommendations at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094187/book-recommendation-for-algebraic-geometry), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998/best-algebraic-geometry-text-book-other-than-hartshorne?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning Algebraic geometry is not a simple task and this is very logic that this gives you a nonsense impression .
I like two references to learn AG the first is Harris an first course (this book is more like a undergraduate book with a lot of context and example and intuition )
The second more advanced is kenji ueno Algebraic geometry

About Hartshorne exercises :
Some of Hartshorne exercises are very difficult and not adequate for learning student but there is Exercises that are very important and you must do but this is normal that get you time keep time to thinking I think that Algebraic geometry is a subject that you need to give time for it for example to learn chapter 1 can keep 2 months and this is okay .
So don't worry about it